# iOS: User removable files in Settings / Usage

Tags: ios, settings, documents, info.plist

In Settings / General / Usage there is an Edit button in the Music and Podcasts apps to **remove the cached or downlaoded files stored by the application**.

However that option doesn't seem to be available in other apps, even if they use the Documents directory.
I've read somewhere that this is a developer-enabled feature (maybe Info.plist?)

**Is this something I can enable my users to do, and if so, how?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your application download file and cache files which user want to remove after a time being you can implement the bundle setting functionality, and you can detect that change when your app launch and delete the files from your document folder.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a hack-y way of doing this? In that case the removal wouldn't be instantaneous as opposed to the immediate free space gained when removing podcasts from the General / Usage / Podcasts settings.

Comment: it's little hack-y way but you can not clear the folder without it, or simply you can provide a functionality like when you see that app is having more unused data then you can show user a pop up and based on that clean it!

Comment: The thing is when my phone is full I go to the Usage section and start axing apps that consume way too much space. The idea was to provide an alternative to the user: sacrifice the cached data, rather than deleting the app.

I wouldn't even think about going to the app's settings before removing it. Not many apps have Settings and it's not the usual place to put content removal options.

Comment: there is no option or no ways to clear the application cache without deleting the app because no app can read the other app document folder so every app has to provide a way to clear its own data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setting bundle for this option. Add a option in setting.

https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH6-SW11